# The sitename.com is't working www.dellbazar.com is currently unable to handle this request Http Error 500

Tags: php, error, magento-1, configuration, installation

I install Magento using softaculous. It installed successfully but after that am having this error. Here is the error log details :

> [20-Dec-2016 14:03:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function **iconv_substr()** in /home/dellbazar/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php on line 103
>
> [20-Dec-2016 14:03:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function **iconv_strpos()** in /home/dellbazar/public_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 486

These errors repeats many times.

Comment: why you want try with `softaculous`, ya its esasy, if possible try to instal with normal magento procedure..... you can check lnk : https://techjam.gr/2012/magento/solve-magento-500-internal-server-errors/

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because on your server the `iconv` PHP extension is turned off. You should find your php configuration file and enable the iconv (line like `;extension=iconv.so` should be uncommented, just remove the `;`).

You can check whether `iconv` extensions is included using a command:

```
php -i | grep "iconv support"
```

Result should look like this:

> iconv support => enabled